# serial console output goes away while booting

Tags: linux, boot, linux-kernel, serial, kernel-panic

I added console=ttyS0,57600n8 to my kernel command line.  I get the normal boot messages until this

> [    5.123106] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
>   Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
>   done.
>   Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.

Then no more output.  I am trying to debug a kernel panic using kdump, but can't quite get kdump to work.  I want the serial console to get kdump working.

[edit] I worked around the problem using a virtual machine.

Comment: You should try removing the "quiet" and hte other option from the grub config too. I can't remember it's name now, sorry. If you post a picture about the grub config (at boot), I'll help you pinpoint the other option too.

Comment: do you want me to hit e and take a pic of the kernel arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will almost certainly also need to update your inittab, or upstart configuration in addition to the kernel options.

init - /etc/inittab

```
T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 57600 vt102
```

Upstart - /etc/init/ttyS0.conf

```
# ttyS0 - getty
#
# This service maintains a getty on ttyS0 from the point the system is
# started until it is shut down again.

start on stopped rc or RUNLEVEL=[2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec /sbin/getty -L ttyS0 57600 vt102
```